# gspread populate google spreadsheet from python no attribute 'update_acell'

Tags: python, google-sheets, raspberry-pi, google-authentication, gspread

I'm stuckle all morning to fill a cell in a google spreadsheet from a python script. 
After running through a couple of out-dated tutorials I can open the spreadsheet, using this script

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('Apps Script Execution APIxxxxxxx.json', scope)
c = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks = c.open_by_key ('1rwPLv6jZBhPGpf38DO6MLxx......')

wks.update_acell('A2','abc')
```

I've tried serveral examples from different tuturials, but I can't find why keep give this error:

AttributeError: 'Spreadsheet' object has no attribute 'update_acell'

Anyone a suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

You need to define the worksheet as well  (Use sheet1 instead of the self given name)

```
ws = wks.get_worksheet(1)

ws.update_acell('A2','abc')
```

If you select the wrong sheet or sheet what don't excists, you get an error like this.
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update_acell'

**UPDATE JULY 2016**

If you have only 1 sheet you should use this:

```
import json
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('YOUR_SECRET_AUTH_JSON_FILE_HERE.json', scope)

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)


wks = gc.open("NAME OF YOUR SPREADSHEET")

ws = wks.get_worksheet(0)



ws.update_acell('A1','IT WORKS!')
```